# How to generate dummy op for torch-to-ONNX export?

Tags: python, pytorch, torchscript

I'm trying to export a torch model to ONNX and, due to some custom operations in the model, I need to generate custom ONNX nodes hwile exporting.
I would like to be able to define a "dummy" operation that I can then use to register a symbolic function handling the ONNX node generation, however I don't know how to tell torchscript to treat the function as an "op" rather than entering and tracing its content:

```py
import torch

# What decorator here? @torch.jit.script parses the body
def my_dummy_fn(first: torch.Tensor, second: torch.Tensor):
    return torch.tensor(0), torch.tensor([1]), torch.tensor([2])

def my_symbolic_function(g, first, second):
    # generate the custom ONNX op via g.op()
    return g.op("my_custon_onnx", first, second)

torch.onnx.register_custom_op_symbolic(
    symbolic_name="??????", # <<<<<<<< What to use here? Ideally, the name of my dummy op
    symbolic_fn=my_symbolic_function,
    opset_version=12,
)
```